# How to copy existing properties of an object to another one in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Consider the following code:

```
const x={name:"a"};
const y={name:"b", fname:"c"};
const z = Object.assign(x,y); //output: z={name:"b", fname:"c"}
//expected: {name:"b"}
```

How to achieve the expected result?

Comment: `Object.assign({name:x.name })`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka: If you're going to be explicit, `{name: x.name}` suffices - `Object.assign` has no use here.

Comment: Note that x is dynamic. I don't know it's properties.

Comment: Why Object.assign() in angular doesn't work as in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign?

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work"? `Object.assign` can't delete properties; you will always end up with both `name` and `fname` if you use `Object.assign`.

Comment: Run example code in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign. It's omit the non-existing properties!

Comment: The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Comment: It didn't omit them - `console.log` just picked to print `c` and `d`. If you inspect the whole object, you'll see `a` is there too.

Comment: Yes. You're right! So is a quick way for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

```js
const x={name:"a"};
const y={name:"b", fname:"c"};
const z = {};
for (let key in x) z[key] = y.hasOwnProperty(key) ? y[key] : x[key];
console.log(z);
```

Comment: Same but shorter: `Object.keys(x).reduce((a, k) => (a[k] = y[k], a), {})` :)

Comment: @Amadan - Even I thought about this. However, I was concerned with the complexity with this. Though it will still be linear but with double the time. Whats your thought about it?

Comment: If I thought it was superior than yours, I'd've made a new answer. So I'm just commenting as an option, if anyone wants to golf, or really prefers an expression to several statements.

Comment: @Amadan - Agreed. Thanks mate :)

Comment: @Amadan - Just another thought, as OP is trying to use `Object.assign`, in case value does exist in `x` and does not exist in `y` then in that case value from `x` shall be honored. What's your thought?

Comment: That should be asked of OP, not of me :D

Comment: @Amadan - hahaha.. My bad :) I hope OP must have got the notification to answer on this

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.prototype.customAssign = function(x,y){
   let item = {};
   Object.keys(x).forEach(function(a,b){ 
      destiKeys.indexOf(a)>=0? item[a] = y[a] : null;
   });
   return item;
};

const x={name:"a"};
const y={name:"b", fname:"c"};
const z = Object.customAssign(x,y); //output: z = {name:"b"}
```

Answer (score 0):

use spreadOperator https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

```
z={...x,..y} //All properties of x + All properties of y
             //y properties replace the sames properties of x
```

Comment: OP doesn't want all properties, just the common ones.

Comment: ::glups:: it's true, sorry